# Read only parts of an XML file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq

```
<Peoples>
 <People>
  <Name>RadheyJang</Name> 
  <Location>India</Location> 
  <Work>Software Developer</Work> 
  <Point>5</Point> 
  <details>
    <People>
    <Name>ArunaTiwari</Name> 
    <Location>India</Location> 
    <Work>SoFtwareCoder</Work> 
    <Point>3</Point> 
    <details/>
    <Test>A</Test>
    </People>
  </details>
  <Test>NA</Test>    
 </People>
</Peoples>
```

I am able to Read That Xml By using below code .

```
                       XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(str);
                       var vrresult = from a in xmlDoc.Descendants("People") 
                       select new
                       {
                           Name= a.Element("Name").Value,
                           Location= a.Element("Location").Value,
                           Point= a.Element("Point").Value
                       };

                        GridView1.DataSource = vrresult;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
```

But It is reading the Contents of details also . I want to Skip reading the Content inside the **details** Element . Please let me know how can i skip the Content Inside the details .

Comment: I've never seen that error message before ... can you please edit your answer and add the GridView markup, and the code that binds your XML?

Comment: no Issue with Gridview Binding . I will Bind But Before Bind at the time of Reading  It is giving Error .

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  I don't have an answer for you, but maybe this link will help:  http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/5/26129.aspx

Comment: It is considered bad practice to change the content of the question as you have done here. The first edit was an error message that you got. Then you changed it to "how to read certain content..". Next time, open a new question.

Comment: May I ask why you want to skip the details content? You'll need to read it anyway to know where the details tag ends (in order to read the rest of the xmlfile). What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: `Descendants` will not discriminate which `People` nodes it looks for.  Need to see the full XML file (or at least it's whole structure) to provide a selector that is more appropriate

Comment: yamen @ not understood . Please let me know some solution for same .It is reading the content of Detail Attribute Also How to Restrict that vale . Required for making Reports

Answer (score 1):

You need to use XPath for this...

```
using System.Xml.XPath;

string xml = @"
    <Peoples>
        <People>
        <Name>RadheyJang</Name> 
        <Location>India</Location> 
        <Work>Software Developer</Work> 
        <Point>5</Point> 
        <details>
            <People>
            <Name>ArunaTiwari</Name> 
            <Location>India</Location> 
            <Work>SoFtwareCoder</Work> 
            <Point>3</Point> 
            <details/>
            <Test>A</Test>
            </People>
        </details>
        <Test>NA</Test>    
        </People>
    </Peoples>";

XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var vrresult = from a in xmlDoc.XPathSelectElements("/Peoples/People")
                select new
                {
                    Name = a.Element("Name").Value,
                    Location = a.Element("Location").Value,
                    Point = a.Element("Point").Value
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var ele = XElement.Parse(xml);
    // change to XElement.Load if loading from file  
    var result = ele.Descendants("Section").Zip(ele.Descendannt("Mark"),  (s,m) => new {Section = s.Value, Mark = m.Value}); Now you can create your DataTable:

    var table = new DataTable(); 
    var marks = new DataColumn("Mark");
    var sections = new     DataColumn("Sections"); 
    table.Columns.Add(marks); table.Columns.Add(sections); 
    foreach (var item in result) 
    {   
     var row = table.NewRow();   
     row["Mark"] = item.Mark;     
     row["Sections"] = item.Section; 
     table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
```

Try this Code ..

Comment: I tried With This Code But I want to Read 3 Values You are Reading Only 2 Value . Please let me know how to Read 3 values and Skip Details Attribute .

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that the XML is not legal:

```
<Peoples>
 <People> *You have an opening People tag here*
  <Name>RadheyJang</Name> 
  <Location>India</Location> 
  <Work>Software Developer</Work> 
  <Point>5</Point> 
  <details> *You create a details tag here*
   <People> *You generate the same tag inside of another People tag*
    <Name>ArunaTiwari</Name> 
    <Location>India</Location> 
    <Work>SoFtwareCoder</Work> 
    <Point>3</Point> 
    <details/> *Then you close the details tag here*
    <Test>A</Test>
    </People>
  </details> *Then you close another one, but there is not a second opening detail tag*
  <Test>NA</Test>    
 </People>
</Peoples>
```

I'm not sure if this helps at all, but you might want to consider fixing up your XML.

Comment: It it system Generated XMl File .

Comment: @rama Still, If one of your applications is creating it then you might want to change how it is generated.

Comment: @MatthewRz He's not closing the `<details>` tag with `<details/>`. That is an empty `<details>` tag. the closing of the tag is done with `</details>`