# Ignore to Read Particular Attibute in Xml File

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read only parts of an XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679499/read-only-parts-of-an-xml-file)

```
<Peoples>
  <People>
  <Name>RadheyJang</Name> 
  <Location>India</Location> 
  <Work>Software Developer</Work> 
  <Point>5</Point> 
  <details>
       <People>
       <Name>ArunaTiwari</Name> 
       <Location>India</Location> 
       <Work>SoFtwareCoder</Work> 
       <Point>3</Point> 
       <details/>
       <Test>A</Test>
       </People>
  </details>
  <Test>NA</Test>    
  </People>
</Peoples>
```

I am able to Read That Xml By using below code .

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(str);
var vrresult = from a in xmlDoc.Descendants("People") 
select new
{
   Name= a.Element("Name").Value,
   Location= a.Element("Location").Value,
   Point= a.Element("Point").Value
};

GridView1.DataSource = vrresult;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

But It is reading the Contents of details also . I want to Skip reading the Content inside the details Element . Please let me know how can i skip the Content Inside the details attribute.